# How to Make Group Content Private if Group is Public and Approval Required?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am using OG 7.x-1.4 version. If a Group is Public & Approval required then Group Content Created Under that group is by default becoming public when i use Group Content Visibility field and select "use group defaults" option.

I think if Group is Public & No Approval required then Group Content Should be public, otherwise access should be restricted to only Group Members.

My Question is, how to set Group Content Visibility field to  Private by default if Group is Public & Approval Required ? One option is using Hook_node_presave !

Any better solution to set default Group Content Visibility based on Group Settings ?